# What is the equivalent Java code of this MATLAB code?

Tags: java, matlab

What is the equivalent Java code of this MATLAB code: `ran = sign(rand-0.5)`?
Is it randomly assigned either 1 or -1 to `ran`? Should I used a Pseudo random number generator that generates randomly 1 or -1?

```
Random rand = new Random(key);
ran = rand.nextInt(1);
```

Comment: Your lack of effort is astonishing.

Comment: :D New to this forum and Matlab. Is it randomly assign either 1 or -1 to ran? Should I used Pseudo random number generator that generate randomly 1 or -1 ?

Comment: Be aware that the negative reaction you got to this question is not without consequences. If you persist in asking poor quality, low effort questions, the site will automatically impose a ban, based on the quality of your previous questions. Even if you delete this question, it will still count against you. So you should take the negative feedback seriously.

Comment: Please have a look at my edits to get an idea of how to better format your questions.  However, formatting does not entirely make up for questions demonstrating lack of research effort, even if [these kinds of questions are evidently now on topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216491/235005) (it's not really unclear).

Comment: thanks for your help. I will try totally to improve the way I write questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double ran = Math.signum(Math.random() - 0.5);
```

The variable ran will contain +1, -1 or sometimes 0.

Comment: What is wrong with the answer? This is exactly what the user aked for.

Comment: The answer might be correct but you really shouldn't be answering these types of questions. OP hasn't shown us that they've tried anything.

Comment: And that is the reason to give -1 ?? Give -1 to the question instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But your code gives 5 as output and The matlab code gives 1 or -1 .

Comment: We gave 8 -1s to the question. Bottom line is: don't provide answers to people that have not shown any effort.

Comment: Why is `Math.round` necessary? The output of the Matlab code is a double. And wouldn't it be better to cast it to long anyways? Also, does `Math.random()` use Mersenne Twister by default or does it need to be set up?

Comment: Fixed according to horchler's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Petr and horchler it works (Wunderbar). No matter what other said you helped me.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No reason to penalize the answerer, IMO. [There is certainly no rule for how to vote on good answers to bad questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203249/235005). Just don't answer if you don't like the question. Petr doesn't mind the lack of effort -- [good for him](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88709/the-lost-worlds-of-the-reversal-badge)!

Comment: Thanks chappjc for your guidance and help.